# How to add exception to random.randint in Python?

Tags: python, random

So I have a variable that creates a random number between 0 and 10, however, I would not like the random number created to be 5. How do I go about adding exceptions to random.randint in Python? What I have below is not doing this:

```
number = random.randint(0, 10) !=5
```

This is only returning True or False based on whether the random number equals 5 or not... how do I fix this?

Comment: Why have I received a downvote?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding exceptions "? Do you want to change how `random.randint` raises exceptions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
number = random.randint(0,10)
while number == 5:
   number = random.randint(0,10)
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
random.choice([x for x in range(11) if x != 5])
```

for a one-liner

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want an error to be raised then you can use `assert`

```
number = random.randint(0, 10)
assert number != 5
```

---

or `raise` an error if your condition is met.

```
number = random.randint(0, 10)
if number == 5:
    raise ValueError # or another Exception of choice
```

---

Or if you want to keep trying until you get a random number that isn't 5, then

```
while True:
    number = random.randint(0, 10)
    if number != 5:
        break
```

Comment: I don't think he's talking about exceptions in the Python meaning of the word.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hence why I gave both options.

Answer (score 0):

!= is actually an operator that returns true or false
try this:

```
import random
l=[i for i in range(1,11)]
l.remove(5)
print random.choice(l)
```